# Design issue when transferring html css into wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress

So I've been asked to develop a custom select menu that renders a submenu based on users choice. Here is the implementation I made using html/css

[image]

However when I copy paste this code into wordpress the design alters and my drop down menu render below the heading texts like so:

[image]

I know h1 is a `block` element so here is my following stylesheet and HTML markup:

```
        <style>
            @import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Playfair+Display:wght@600&display=swap");
            * {
                font-family: "Playfair Display", serif;
                box-sizing: border-box;
            }
            .container {
                width: 1700px;
                margin: 10px 200px;
            }

            body {
                background-color: #1d1345;
                color: #f4f4f4;
            }

            .heading {
                font-size: 60px;
                display: inline-block;
                margin-right: 10px;
            }
            select {
                font-size: 40px;
            }
            #output {
                width: 400px;
            }
        </style>
    


        <div class="container">
            <div class="top">
                <h1 class="heading">I am a</h1>
                <select name="type" id="type">
                    <option value="" selected></option>
                    <option value="futurestudent">Future Student</option>
                    <option value="currentstudent">Current Student</option>
                    <option value="faculty">Faculty</option>
                    <option value="parent">Parent</option>
                    <option value="accreditor">Accreditor</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="bottom">
                <h1 class="heading">Looking for</h1>
                <select name="output" id="output"></select>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: the source design might be using js and other css which i think you are missing in your file

Comment: Yes I wrote some JS but that was only to populate the submenu Items and has nothing to do with the way the component is to be designed so I did not put it up here.

Comment: then it seems like your wordpress default theme css is working instead of your custom css, make sure you added the css at correct place so that it overrides the wordpress theme css, you can even look for plugin for wordpress custom css ,
this might be helpful : https://css-tricks.com/methods-overriding-styles-wordpress/